# How could assign ArrayBuffer[Implementation] to ArrayBuffer[Interface] in Scala

Tags: scala, arraybuffer

I'm trying to do something like below in Scala

```
val buffer1:ArrayBuffer[Element] = ???
val buffer:ArrayBuffer[IElement] = buffer1
```

Which the IElement is my custom interface, and the Element is one element of the implementation.
But the scala compiler shows me an error like this:

> Expression of type ArrayBuffer[Element] doesn't conform to expected type ArrayBuffer[IElement]

How could I get it passed by the compiler?
Does the scala ArrayBuffer support that?

Comment: TL;DR; use an immutable collection that is covariant like **List**, **Vector** or **ArraySeq**. - And if you do not know what variance is, then first learn that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the Scala Type Hierarchy in [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html#:%7E:text=Scala%20Type%20Hierarchy&text=Any%20has%20two%20direct%20subclasses,which%20carries%20no%20meaningful%20information.). As you can see the Int type does not extend from Object so you can not initialize an ArrayBuffer[Object] with an Int value. You have to change the objet to **AnyVal**. Besides, it is invariant in its type. That means that two declarations like:

```
var buffer:ArrayBuffer[AnyVal] = ArrayBuffer.apply(1)
```

and

```
var buffer2:ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer.apply(1)
```

They are not the same so if you try to do something like:

```
buffer = buffer2
```

The compiler gives you the following error:

```
error: type mismatch;
        found   : scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]
        required: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[AnyVal]
       Note: Int <: AnyVal, but class ArrayBuffer is invariant in type A.
       You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: AnyVal`. (SLS 3.2.10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that helps me. But I think I just had written a wrong sample to find my answer. So I will edit my question.